# How to ensure that all the database operations complete before database shuts down in Fluent?

Tags: swift, vapor, vapor-fluent

Fluent operations work in an Asynchronous way and returns the EventLoopFuture, when an operation gets completed. So, if the code uses the database `shutdown` call, is there a way to make sure that all the initiated database operations gets completed, before the database shuts down?

For example, the below code compiles well but does not ensure the insertion of the building object in the database (`Building` is a Fluent `Model`.). On the other hand, if I use the `wait` function with the `create` function, the operation gets synchronous, but ensures the creation a building-record in database.

```
func testExample() throws {
        let dbs = Databases(threadPool: .init(numberOfThreads: System.coreCount), on: MultiThreadedEventLoopGroup(numberOfThreads: System.coreCount))
        try dbs.use(.postgres(url: "<CONNECTIONSTRING>"), as: .psql)
        
        let db = dbs.database(.psql, logger: Logger(label: "Test"), on: dbs.eventLoopGroup.next())!
    
        let building = Building(id: UUID("b0c8f088-df0a-4253-98e4-eb8943c054d4"), buildingName: "Building4")
        building.create(on: db)
        // This is synchronous and would create a record in the database.
        //try building.create(on: db).wait()
        
        dbs.shutdown()
        try dbs.threadPool.syncShutdownGracefully()
        try dbs.eventLoopGroup.syncShutdownGracefully()
    }
```

Is there a way to make `dbs.shutdown()` wait until the `create` operation (or any initiated database operation) completes?

Answer (score 1):

The problem you're hitting is that you're trying to make an asynchronous operation work in a synchronous function. In short - you can't.

You either need to call `wait()` as you show in your comments to make the function synchronous or you need to make the function asynchronous and return a future. There's no other way around it.

But to answer your other question if you want call shutdown after the create function you need to wait for the future to return using either `map` or `flatMap`

Comment: I have tried using flatMap for shutting down the connections, but I was receiving some threading errors while doing that. Now, I'm trying to close the connections in deinit, it's seeming to work at least for now.